# Broadcast receiver start activity

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have an application that using "AlarmService". For handling alarms i have a Broadcast receiver. That receiver has to start certain activity. Code i'm using for achieving that is following:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...other code....
    Intent intIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intIntent .putExtra("IsAlarm", true);
    Intent alarmChooser = Intent.createChooser(intIntent , "Alarm");
    alarmChooser.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(alarmChooser);
}
```

That works but only if activity isn't shown already (if it's not in the foreground). If called activity is already opened nothing happens. How can i overcome that?
Is there a flag that will start the activity if it's not started OR send intent to it even if it's in the foreground?

P.S. i tried using dedicated "broadcast" above the provided code. Reciever for that broadcast is registered programmatically in the MainActivity: "onResume" would register dedicated receiver, "onPause" would unregister it. That way in case MainActivity is already on it will receive a broadcast but then i have a problem when phone goes to "stand by" - "dedicated" receiver is unregistered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in the activity `onNewIntent` callback 
 there should be the new intent from the receiver

Comment: Should i use android:launchMode="singleTop" for MainActivity in that case?

Comment: you can set that in launchMode , or you can set that flag in the intent "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP "

Comment: Won't do :( In any case "onNewIntent" isn't called at all

Comment: you need to add this flags to the intent  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

Comment: Yes, i did that :) I tried with "CLEAR_TOP" as well!

Comment: it's work for me activity with launchMode=singleTop and intent: Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Comment: Is there a chance "Intent.createChooser" is causing problems? I wasn't able to start the activity without it (that's why i had to add it)

Comment: try to remove it, I never used that method

Comment: Yes, that (together with your response) did the trick! Thank you! Xorg will get +1 because he's answer was part of the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the chooser:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent intIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intIntent.putExtra("IsAlarm", true);
    context.startActivity(intIntent);
}
```